# iframe issue in Firefox - Not showing up at all

Tags: html, facebook, firefox, iframe

I am developing a webpage for a client, and they want to have their Facebook feed in a sidebar. I was happy to find out that it is very easy to embed a Facebook feed, but was unhappy to see that it doesn't seem to work.

After really scratching my head on the issue, I decided "hey, maybe it just isn't working in Firefox", so I factored down to the least common denominator and fired up IE - sure enough, it shows up with no issue in IE. Here is a screenshot of the difference:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtAfC.png

To make matters a little more strange, this isn't a universal issue in Firefox for me. iframes are showing up great *everywhere else*. The W3Schools test page, for instance, shows up fine... unless I'm using the Facebook code. For those unfamiliar with it, Facebook provides automatically generated code for feed embeds, and it is as follows:

```
 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I suspect since this is the only frame that is giving me issues, there's something wrong with Facebook's code, but it strikes me as odd that a web giant such as Facebook would provide developers with faulty code that was untested on a popular web browser.

Is there something wrong with Facebook's code? My Firefox? Help much appreciated.

Comment: I think this might rather be an issue of “social plugins” being blocked for privacy reasons ... Check the browser console, and see if it says anything in that regard there.

Comment: @CBroe This seems like it might be the issue, although Facebook offers a preview on their website that shows up fine, and the developer page on Firefox says that "tracking" is only blocked in private windows, which is what it claims it is blocking in my console.

Comment: While you're in the developer section, this is treated as content from the same base domain - whereas once you embed it into your site, it becomes 3rd-party content, and that is what privacy extensions usually block. I was under the impression, too, that Firefox only blocks this by default in private mode; looks like either that has changed now, or maybe you have another extension running that blocks this ...?

Comment: @CBroe I am only using uBlock Origin on this computer. There is nothing in the settings blocking social sites like this, but I feel like you're on the right track about this, as I have visited another website that I know has a twitter feed, and it is missing now, too. I have a different computer that allows that twitter feed to show up, but is using the same uBlock setup.